# A positive integer $n$ is such that $1-2x+3x^2-4x^3+5x^4-...-2014x^{2013}+nx^{2014}$ has at least one integer solution. Find $n$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, proof-writing, arithmetic, integers

> A positive integer $n$ is such that $$1-2x+3x^2-4x^3+5x^4-...-2014x^{2013}+nx^{2014}$$ has at least one integer solution. Find $n$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the rational root test, the possible rational roots of the polynomial have the form
$$
r=\frac{1}{k}
$$
where $k$ is an integer (positive or negative) that divides $n$. Which of them are integer? When are they roots of the polynomial?

Comment: $r$ is integer only if $k=1$. Then don't we have $1 + 1006 - 2014 + n =0$, whence $n=1007$?

Comment: @VincenzoOliva If $k=1$ or $k=-1$. In the second case you want $1+2+3+\dots+2014+n=0$ (which is not compatible with $n>0$); in the first case you want $1-2+3-4+\dots+2013-2014+n=0$. The sum can be computed easily as $(1+2\dots+2014)-2(2+4+\dots+2014)=2014\cdot2015/2-4\cdot1007\cdot1008/2$.

Comment: Oh sorry, I wasn't paying enough attention as I was having lunch and forgot about $−1$. Yes, thank you for your method of computation too. I worked out $n=1007$ by noting that after $1$, we have 1006 pairs of numbers in the form $(-m+m+1)$. I didn't know this rational root test, is it usually done after high school?

Comment: @VincenzoOliva It's usually done *in* high school! In Italy, I mean. But it's easy to see that if $p/q$ (reduced fraction) is a root of the polynomial $a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_nx^n$ with integer coefficients, then $p$ divides $a_0$.

Comment: Oh dear, dear... another reason for hating my school. I better study on my own thoroughly every topic we dealt with in class, it seems.

Comment: Yes, I agree it's easy to see it, but I believe it is not so easy/natural to think about it. Or at least, not yet to me, without knowing already the test.

Answer (score 5):

If you believe the question, that you are looking for one possible value of $n$, then you should be able to find one by setting $f(1)=0$ which clearly gives you a linear equation for $n$. Why doesn't $f(-1)=0$ work?

You need something like @egreg's approach to show there are no other possibilities.

Comment: Yes, that's true, letting $x=1$ easily yields $n=1007$. It was a question in a time trial, I didn't really get at it. Then I asked the question just when I arrived home, and I went eating. I was thinking anyway of something like egreg's answer.